# Problem with RSA implementation with WinAPI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, bcrypt

So I use the CNG framwork from windows in my software(which written exclusively with c).
The problem is when I try to implement RSA in my code

The code looks something like this:

```
    DWORD temp = BCRYPT_SUPPORTED_PAD_OAEP;

    BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(PointerToAlgorithmProvider, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
    
    BCryptGenerateKeyPair(ActualAlgorithmProvider, &handleToKeyObject, 2048, 0);
    
    BCryptSetProperty(ActualAlgorithmProvider, BCRYPT_PADDING_SCHEMES, (PUCHAR)&temp, sizeof(DWORD), 0);

.
.
.
```

Unfortunately, `BCryptSetProperty` return with Invalid handle error.

Comment: It seems that [`BCRYPT_PADDING_SCHEMES`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/bcrypt.h#L261) is for `BCryptGetProperty` according to the comment. And have you tried it in kernel mode, open the provider handle with `BCRYPT_PROV_DISPATCH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm from the developer: `BCRYPT_PADDING_SCHEMES` is used to retrieve the **padding schemes supported by the RSA algorithm provider**. If you want to use one of the supported padding schemes(OAEP padding scheme for example), you can specify the `BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP` flag in [`BCryptEncrypt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt)/[`BCryptDecrypt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptdecrypt).

Answer (score 1):

One problem is incorrect usage of `BCryptSetProperty`. The `BCRYPT_SUPPORTED_PAD_OAEP` symbol is not a variable, it’s a preprocessor macro.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-property-identifiers) for `BCRYPT_PADDING_SCHEMES` says “data type is a DWORD”, this means the size is 4 bytes.

To set that property, declare a local `DWORD` variable and pass the address to the function:

```
DWORD val = BCRYPT_SUPPORTED_PAD_OAEP;
BCryptSetProperty( ActualAlgorithmProvider, BCRYPT_PADDING_SCHEMES, (PUCHAR)(&val), 4, 0 );
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the function still returns with INVALID_HANDLE

Comment: @TheAsker Yeah, that’s why I started with “one problem is” :-) Unfortunately, the code you have posted doesn’t tell the full story, i.e. how you initialize your `PointerToAlgorithmProvider` and `ActualAlgorithmProvider` variables.

Comment: I edited, hope it will shed a little bit more light on the situation